# SQL Query for finding a column name where matching text is in column

Tags: sql, sqlite, wildcard

This is my first stakoverflow question, although I've lurked for quite a while.  I'm writing a webapp in PHP/SQLite, and I'm trying to find a column name along with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT lexemeid FROM lexeme, sense WHERE lexeme.lexemeid =
sense.senselexemeid AND (lexeme.lexeme LIKE '%apani%' OR lexeme.variant
LIKE '%apani%' OR lexeme.affixedform LIKE '%apani%' OR sense.example
LIKE '%apani%');
```

Basically, I'm offering a full text lookup for a few different fields.  The query above works, but I'd like to get the name of the column where my wildcard matches for each result as well.  Basically I want something like the above query with the SELECT looking more like:

```
SELECT lexemeid, COLUMN NAME FROM...
```

I'd also welcome any ideas for making my SQL Query look/perform better (maybe using LIKE and IN??).  I'm basically trying to join lexeme.lexemeid and sense.senselexemeid and do a wildcard lookup on a text string (in this case, "apani").

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have a match in one of the columns, you could use a CASE statement.

```
SELECT lexemeid,
       CASE WHEN lexeme.lexeme LIKE '%apani%' THEN 'lexeme'
            WHEN lexeme.variant LIKE '%apani%' THEN 'variant'
            ...
            WHEN sense.example LIKE '%apani%' THEN 'example'
       END AS ColumnName
    FROM ...
```

Comment: That'll do it, all right.  What happens if there is a match in one of the columns?  I'd like to have each lexemeid show up, with the columns showing up in a weighted order (listed in my query above from the most important to least important).  I mean, if something matches all four columns, I want my query to return: 903|lexeme, but if it only matches the last two, I want it to return 903|affixedform.  Will reversing the order of my query do this?

Comment: To answer my own comment, it looks like it already does exactly what it is supposed to.  Thanks!